# Why won't macOS Catalina create/use the default route?

Tags: networking, macos, dns, routing

I'm trying to debug why my Mac won't connect properly to a Hilton Hotel Wi-Fi (and I think it's the Mac's fault). The issue is that I appear to successfully connect to the Wi-Fi and receive an IP, but the captive login page never appears and I can't access any websites (a MacBook Pro, Catalina 10.15.1).

I'm beginning to suspect macOS is being too clever by half with its captive portal detection, but I'm not sure. Troubleshooting output is listed below. Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

The tl;dr questions are:

- What does the `I` flag mean on a route and why won't my machine use a default route with an `I` flag?
- Why is macOS creating the default route with the `I` when connecting over Wi-fi?
- Is this related captive portal sniffing?
- Thoughts on how to fix this?

First, I verified the DHCP response. Sniffing the response with tcpdump, I get:

```
21:46:11.728741 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 62639, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    192.168.28.1.67 > 192.168.28.176.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, xid 0xfe73a282, Flags [none]
      Your-IP 192.168.28.176
      Client-Ethernet-Address f0:18:98:XX:XX:XX [hidden from s/o post]
      Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
        Magic Cookie 0x63825363
        DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: ACK
        Server-ID Option 54, length 4: 192.168.28.1
        Lease-Time Option 51, length 4: 85361
        Subnet-Mask Option 1, length 4: 255.255.252.0
        Default-Gateway Option 3, length 4: 192.168.28.1
        Domain-Name-Server Option 6, length 8: 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
```

So I'm receiving an IP, a default route, and DNS at 8.8.8.8. When I attempt to ping 8.8.8.8, however, I get:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
```

So my machine can't access the DNS servers, and this is confirmed if I try to use dig:

```
logan@bender (OSX) $ dig @8.8.8.8 captive.apple.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @8.8.8.8 captive.apple.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

So it looks like it's a routing issue, and lo, if I try to get a route, I can't:

```
logan@bender (OSX) $ route get default
route: writing to routing socket: not in table
```

BUT, there is a default route in the table:

```
logan@bender (OSX) $ netstat -rn | grep default
default            192.168.20.1       UGScI          en0
default                                 fe80::%utun0                    UGcI          utun0
default                                 fe80::%utun1                    UGcI          utun1
default                                 fe80::%utun2                    UGcI          utun2
default                                 fe80::%utun3                    UGcI          utun3
```

The issue seems to be the `I` flag on the route. If I plug in a USB network adapter, the default route is slightly different for that interface and it works fine:

```
logan@bender (OSX) $ netstat -rn | grep default
default            192.168.211.1      UGSc          en15
default            192.168.20.1       UGScI          en0
default                                 fe80::%utun0                    UGcI          utun0
default                                 fe80::%utun1                    UGcI          utun1
default                                 fe80::%utun2                    UGcI          utun2
default                                 fe80::%utun3                    UGcI          utun3
```

I suspect the behavior might be related to how macOS detects captive portals; the ethernet connection does not have one. I was able to complete the captive portal on my iPhone.

Comment: Hmm. 28 vs. 20 in the third octet. Also, all those utunX tunnel devices getting IPv6 routes…you aren't running a full-tunnel VPN, are you? Those can block your ability to talk to a captive portal. Disable your VPN software and try again. Also, try loading [http://httpforever.com](http://httpforever.com/) from a web browser in order to provide an insecure connection attempt for the captive portal to hijack.

Comment: The usual trick is to browse to http://captive.apple.com/ & see if that forces it open.